# Testing (JUnit) SQL DELETE and UPDATE statement without commiting

Tags: java, sql, commit

Is there any way to do that? I want to test some SQL requests containing DELETE and UPDATE statements but don't want to commit the change.

Comment: Turn auto-commit off and do your SELECT in the same transaction as your UPDATE or DELETE?

Comment: What do you actually need to test? If you skip the commit, you will also miss any checks that are implemented in deferrable constraints (if your DB supports them). Usually, you test data access so that you set up the database (dedicated test DB or in-memory DB) before you run the tests and clean up / discard the DB after the tests have been run.

Comment: Sounds like integration testing, not unit testing to me

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on RDBMS you are using. In Oracle you can rollback anything until you execute commit. In transactional DBs usually there is an option to open transaction, mess with some data and than close or rollback.

Best way though is to make a copy of a table with a slice of data and try everything there.

PS: Don't mess with Prod! :)